# My app is crashing when scan invalid String by using Qr scanner

Tags: java, android

I am beginner to android...from qr scanner i am scanning data...code is working 
fine...suposse if i scan some string like abc...my app is crashing ...because of less character...how avoid crashing...if i scan some invalid string in below code...can anyone help me...

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

            String Id = contents.substring(0, 10),
                    password = contents.substring(10, 14);
            //    formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + contents);
            //  contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + format);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
          setdetails(id.toString(), password.toString());



      } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
      // Handle cancel
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

       toast.show();

  }

    } else
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 
>       ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {       act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN
>   flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to    activity {com.application}:
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:   length=7; regionStart=0;
>   regionLength=10

```
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3720)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; regionStart=0; regionLength=10
```

Comment: Post your exception and stacktrace please

Comment: can you see edited code..i posted exception

Comment: add try catch and show the message to user about the invalid data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make sure string length is not less than 14 (in your case)
and it's not null too
use this code:

```
//...some code ...
String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
if(contents!=null && contents.length() >= 14){
    String Id = contents.substring(0, 10),
    password = contents.substring(10, 14);
    //    formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + contents);
    //  contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + format);

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    setdetails(id.toString(), password.toString());   
}else{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: previously...its scanning displaying result ..for 14 string....now if i put above code...its not scanning result at all

Answer (score 0):

Can you just tell what is the error showing in error log, which scanner you are using.

As of zxing barcode scanner itself gives error dialog "Error, Cannot interpret QR code." is displayed.

Comment: please check above...i posted exception

Comment: Hello Kingraj,
what you can do here is check in which line you are getting index out of bound exception, from error log itself 
you can handle exception using try catch and can display error dialog like zxing barcode scanner in your catch block.

Either handle IndexOutOfBoundsException here or simply handle Exception